# How can a background service know if activity is killed or not

Tags: android

I have an activity that starts a background service. Once it is started, it runs forever.

Lets say the background service needs the activity that started it to update something. Then how can I start the activity again "If it is not started" however if it is already started then send a broadcast?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to [bind](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService(android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int)) to the service in your activity. Then, in the service, implement the [onBind](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onBind(android.content.Intent)) and [onUnbind](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onUnbind(android.content.Intent)) methods to set a boolean "bound". Check the boolean to see whether the activity is active.

Comment: Hmmmm... That's a great solution!. I never thought of it. Accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

With activity you mean the service's process. If the service is started forever, then its process its started foerever (except when the system kill its for recovering memory purpose and recreates it later). That doesnt mean the rest of activities/fragments/services are not kill. A service is just an entry point for your application and it gives your process a position into the process priority ladder.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say, since I don't know the details of your app, but I think that you may want to consider a bit of a redesign.

As you have noticed, Activities are ephemeral. Generally speaking, a service should not (cannot) depend on a particular Activity being active.

In fact, a well-designed service should not depend on any particular activity at all.

Comment: Well the problem is I do a license check in the service. So if it fails, I want to start the activity and show its dialog box.

Comment: Does the license check need to be done continuously, or can you check just on Activity transitions? You could create a base Activity class, and check in it's onResume  method, then start the desired Activity from there if the license is not valid.

Comment: That's the thing, I only have one activity, which starts a service and then it goes to onPause. User may never open the activity again so I want to do the license check every 20 days (subscription model)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely follow your question. However, when communicating from a Service to an Activity I use a broadcast receiver in the Activity class.

This can be created as follows:

// register the BroadcastReceiver in your activity class

```
this.receiver = new NotificationReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("com.example.LISTENER");
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

// insert in your activity class

```
class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.hasExtra("command")) {
            if(intent.getStringExtra("command").equals("userRegistered")) {

            // insert code to do something when this intent is received

            }
        }
    }
}
```

// insert in your service class to send message

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.example.LISTENER");
i.putExtra("command", "userRegistered");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

Comment: And what if the activity is not started? That's my question, how can I know if activity is started to send a broadcast

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand your scenario. When you send the broadcast it will be received whether the activity is started or not. Is the scenario that you don't want to send the broadcast if the activity isn't started? If so I'm not sure I understand why. You can update the state of the activity so next time it is started it will display the info about the failed license check. I'm assuming you don't want to force the app to the foreground with an error dialog. For these types of messages I usually use Toast.makeText(...).show();

Comment: If you send a broadcast to an activity that is not started, then nothing will happen as there no receiver to that broadcast. I want something to happen "always" even if it means recreating the activity again

Comment: I would suggest showing a notification in the case where the license check fails and the activity isn't currently in the foreground. This way you don't create a jarring experience for the user. This is the purpose of notifications in Android, to gently interrupt the user that something has happened within an application even when the user isn't running the application.